# Are German families migrating in some noticeable number to theoretically non-Muslim-friendly countries because of fear of Muslims?

Tags: europe, immigration

I've read that in some online newspapers that are pretty politically far right, so they may not be exactly objective, but I've found some other web pages that make the claim so it looks a bit more plausible.

Here are some of the places that support the claim:

http://hungarytoday.hu/news/mirror-migration-germans-moving-hungary-fear-migrants-20317

http://www.therebel.media/mass_migrant_influx_makes_german_family_flee_to_russia_as_asylum_seekers_because_germany_is_not_safe_anymore

Well, the last one doesn't specifically talk about families rather about one family, but it helps to support the claim anyway.

There are also some other web sites (not an insane amount but some) that support the claim.

How true is the claim really? What I want to learn from asking "how true it is" is a good estimation of the number of families that have moved because of that. I mean if 3 families have moved it doesn't deserve much consideration, but if there are e.g 200, it deserves some at least.

Comment: Germans call this [Überfremdung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberfremdung).

Comment: Sorry this question is a mess. I tried to fix it but I can't. (a) it asks about motivations, which is not allowed here; (b) how many family does it take to satisfy this claim? one example claim says *one* family emigrated but it's hardly surprising that *some* families move to Russia; (c) what are non-Muslim-friendly countries?

Comment: Moving from Germany to Russia to avoid muslims seems a bit like moving from USA to Canada to avoid state-backed healthcare policies... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_Russia

Comment: @user568458 - that's a rather... un-nuanced view of the reality. Islam in Russia is (1) very geographically localized as far as native population; (2) There are very few Muslim immigrants from areas outside of former USSR's Muslim republics; (3) Most Muslims are significantly less... "radicalized" seems to be the term in vogue at the moment; (4) Most are far more culturally "soviet" than "Middle Eastern" - the issue is far more frequently about culture than religion. I won't even go into differences related to more disputable political factors, like german PC government outright hiding crimes